# Extremely Slow Performing SELECT

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a table with with 7,526,511 records with the following definition:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[LogSearches]    Script Date: 12/07/2009 09:23:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogSearches](
    [ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Acct_ID] [int] NULL,
    [RecordCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PageNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Site_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SearchAPI] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [FormSearch] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IPAddress] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Domain] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ScriptName] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [QueryString] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Referer] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL,
    [SearchString] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [UserAgent] [nvarchar](2048) NULL,
    [Processed] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IntegerIP] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LogSearches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogSearches] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_LogSearches_Processed]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Processed]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogSearches] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_LogSearches_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Created]
GO
```

The execution plan looks like this:

```
StmtText                                                                                 StmtId      NodeId      Parent      PhysicalOp                     LogicalOp                      Argument                                                 DefinedValues                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    EstimateRows  EstimateIO    EstimateCPU   AvgRowSize  TotalSubtreeCost OutputList                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Warnings Type                                                             Parallel EstimateExecutions
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ----------- ---------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM LogSearches                                                          1           1           0           NULL                           NULL                           1                                                        NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1             NULL          NULL          NULL        0.0032832        NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL     SELECT                                                           0        NULL
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))                                                           1           2           1           Top                            Top                            TOP EXPRESSION:((1))                                     NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1             0             1E-07         11848       0.0032832        [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[ID], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[Acct_ID], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[RecordCount], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[PageNumber], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[Site_ID], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[SearchAPI], [LOALo NULL     PLAN_ROW                                                         0        1
       |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[PK_LogSearches]))  1           3           2           Clustered Index Scan           Clustered Index Scan           OBJECT:([LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[PK_LogSearches])  [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[ID], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[Acct_ID], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[RecordCount], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[PageNumber], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[Site_ID], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[SearchAPI], [LOALo 1             2956.71       8.279319      11848       0.0032831        [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[ID], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[Acct_ID], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[RecordCount], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[PageNumber], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[Site_ID], [LOALogs].[dbo].[LogSearches].[SearchAPI], [LOALo NULL     PLAN_ROW                                                         0        1

(3 row(s) affected)
```

When I run the query it doesn't finish in any sort of reasonable time frame. I've let the query run for over 5 minutes, and it still didn't return the single row I asked for. This type of slow SELECT performance is having other effects on the database, such as making it difficult to get rid of rows we no longer need.

Do you have an idea where my bottleneck might be? The 98 gig database and its logs are running on SQL Server 2008 on a 4-disk RAID 10 with over 100 gigs of free space on the drives.

Comment: are you sure that the row(s) you are selecting aren't being blocked by the row / page / db being locked by another process ? Try adding with (NoLock) to the end of your query and see if that helps

Comment: Does it return when you use (NOLOCK)

Comment: It does return with NOLOCK. Looks like I made a noob mistake because I've been dealing with this table for so. damned. long. It's taking me forever to clear out rows we no longer need.

Comment: When your crisis is over if you are on SQL 2005 /8 you might want to look at partitioned tables for your log file; you can partition the data so that with a little maintenance current months log data goes into one table and the rest is in another. Can be a very usefull tool; if you are on enterprise you can set things as offline or readonly which is even better.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely interested in partitioning out the table by dates, I just have to figure out how to work it. The docs out there seem overly technical for what should be something fairly simple to set up.

Comment: This is a simple easy one to follow (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/);

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that article a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked to see if you are having a blocking issue?

Comment: I had been the last few days I've been fighting with this table, but didn't this time around. It looks like that might be the issue after all. I've had *continuous* issues trying to get records deleted from this table, and made the false assumption that it was the same old stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be useful to create another table with required structure and copy/"pump" data there, then delete old table and rename new one? You may need to do it in "batches" for specific id range:

```
INSERT INTO LogSearches_new ... SELECT * FROM LogSearches WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 999999
```

Comment: Unfortunately that solution caused just as many problems as the original delete when I tried it :-(. I think I've having Disk I/O issues that I need to resolve to speed this up. Been running PerfMon for 24 hours, so we'll see what it has to say.